# Issue with CSS3 rotation

Tags: css, svg, rotation, transform

I'm having issues with CSS3 rotation. On the image, you can see the SVG object that I need to animate on hover. The object on the left is a start state, and the object on the right is an example of what I have to accomplish.

I have tried with this:

```
.svg-pokazivac {
   transition: .2s all ease-in-out;
}
.svg-pokazivac:hover {
   transform: rotate(45deg);
   transform-origin: center center;
}
```

But no matter what I do and which transform-origin I choose, I always get the object that is somehow misplaced and translated to some strange position. The closest I've got to solution so far is with a code that looks like this:

```
.svg-pokazivac:hover {
   transform: translate(350px,-150px) rotate(45deg);
}
```

But animation of that is very funny. What i'm doing wrong?

[image: Objects]

Comment: Can you provide us with enough code to replicate the issue or provide a live demo? My guess is you're not taking into account the arrow part

Comment: Of course, here is the complete scene: http://jsfiddle.net/3c7zf4uq/

Comment: That fiddle has no rotation animation (at least on Chrome)

Comment: @MichaelMullany Just add the code in the question

Comment: @IgorHrcek I'd recommend splitting the circle and the arrow into 2 paths, it'll be easier to calculate the proper transform origin

Comment: Something like that crossed my mind, thanks Zach!

Comment: I've splitted the circle and the arrow, but I still have a lot of problems with right transform-origin calculation. Here is the new code: http://jsfiddle.net/3c7zf4uq/2/ What I managed to do is to somehow, using translation, put it in the place (almost). Also, I have problem with hover on one of the pieces, the arrow should go green but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few mugs of coffee, I finally managed to do it. What I did was to remove the pointer and the circle completely from the SVG element and remake them in a pure CSS:

```
.svg-pointer {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 45.5px 46px 45.5px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #4e4e4e transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 125px;
    left: 306px;
    transform-origin: 50% 227px;
}

.svg-circle {
    width: 379px;
    height: 379px;
    border-radius: 999px;
    background: #4e4e4e;
    position: absolute;
    top: 161px;
    left: 159px;
}
```

The rest is just a javascript transition manipulation. You can see the whole solution here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/3c7zf4uq/7/

Also, I would like to point to this very helpful article which helped me a lot: http://demosthenes.info/blog/860/Animating-Elements-In-Arcs-Circles-and-Ellipses-With-CSS

I hope that it would help someone with similar problems :)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the weird behavior because the transition: all is causing a transition between two different transform origins - the default and your explicitly specified one. Now the silent default for a CSS transform origin is supposed to be 50% 50% - so this shouldn't be a problem, but clearly Chrome thinks that the silent default for an SVG shape is the default for SVG transforms of 0% 0%. [Likely Bug!] If you add a transform origin to your base class it works just fine.

```
.svg-pokazivac {
   transition: .2s all ease-in-out;
       transform-origin: 347px 347px;
}
.svg-pokazivac:hover {
   transform: rotate(1805deg);
   transform-origin: 347px 347px;
}
```

Note that 50% 50% for transform-origin doesn't quite work because the pointer is being included in the calculation of the center. Also, you might think you could fix this by switching from transition all to transition transform (excluding transform-origin) but this doesn't work. Only specifying the transform origin in the base class does the trick.